# UIKit SDK 3.0 error

Tags: iphone, uikit

I am using iphone_sdk_3.0_beta_5__9m2735 SDK. 
When I try to compile my code using simulator 3.0 option I get following error. The code compiles for rest all simulator option ie 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.2.1 
While compiling my code I get following error

```
from /Users/videomac/manish/EXPLab/2009-05-27-11-20 myApp_LL_2/myApp_Prefix.pch:7:
In file included from /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:30,
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UILocalizedIndexedCollation.h:11: error: syntax error before 'AT_NAME' token
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UILocalizedIndexedCollation.h:19: error: syntax error before '}' token
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UILocalizedIndexedCollation.h:21: fatal error: method definition not in @implementation context
```

The errors are located in file UILocalizedIndexedCollation.h which is SDK file.I am using UIKit Framework of SDK 3.0. Can anyone tell me what should I do to remove this error?

Answer (score 6):

I've traced this problem to be the compiler version being used. From what I can tell, [REDACTED] requires GCC 4.2 while iPhone SDK 2.x only works with GCC 4.0.

Here's a way to fix this.

In your `Target Info`, select `Build` separator and look for the section `Compiler Version`. Then:

1. Select the `C/C++ Compiler Version` row
2. Set the default to `GCC 4.0`
3. At the bottom-left control, hit `Add Build Setting Condition`
4. On the left, choose `Device - iPhone OS 3.0`
5. On the right, chose `GCC 4.2`
6. Repeat steps 3 to 5, now with `Simulator - iPhone OS 3.0` on step 4.

Comment: Hi jpedroso
I did follow the above steps but I am getting same 3 errors.

Comment: One clarification: for step 3 you need to have selected the "C/C++ Compiler Version" build setting, otherwise "Add Build Setting Condition" is greyed out.  That stumped me for a bit!

Once I'd done that these instructions fixed the problem for me.  Manish - did you try a Clean build?

Answer (score 4):

Apple’s engineer had confirmed that they had a bug in UIKit framework:

We do have a simple workaround for this UIKit bug. In UILocalizedIndexedCollation.h change this:

```
UIKIT_EXTERN @interface UILocalizedIndexedCollation : NSObject
to
UIKIT_EXTERN_CLASS @interface UILocalizedIndexedCollation : NSObject
```

Denis2342

Comment: This problem is only for the 3.0 SDK. Version 3.1 don't have it.

Comment: awesome, this is a royal pain in the ass, and now its fixed. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should discuss beta products here.

However, this is not connected with the beta. You have an error in one of your own header filesprobably a missing '@end' statment.

BTW, google could have solved this for you rather than asking here.

Comment: @Roger, I think you meant we "shouldn't" discuss beta products here.